# Problems executing block of code in JAVA, code does not run completely when you first click

Tags: java, netbeans

tried to run this code but it only runs once when I try to do two or more times it does nothing

I have already compiled the program and it makes it perfect but it doesn't show the changes to the user

```
event = button.getName();

switch (event) {
    case "   EMPLOYEE":


      if (click == true) {

            btn_asist.setLocation(10, 300);
            btn_asist.setEnabled(false);
            sub_menu_employee.setLocation(20, 180);
            click = false;

      }
      else if (sub_menu_employee.isVisible() && (!click == true)) {
            sub_menu_employee.setVisible(false);

            btn_asist.setLocation(10, 180);
            btn_asist.setEnabled(true);
            click = true;

      }

      break;
}
```

I expected that when you click on an option the sub menu will open and when you click again it will close.
and if once again you want to click on the same option work the same but it doesn't work the second time

Comment: Where is `sub_menu_employee.setVisible(true);`?

Comment: are you sure that `sub_menu_employee` is visible on the second try , because you are checking for it in the else if block here `sub_menu_employee.isVisible()`

Comment: @MaartenBodewes 
is in the actionPerformed method of the button that is clicked then i call this method

Comment: @ZOLDIK Yes, cause 
sub_menu_employee.setVisible (true); is in the actionperformed method when clicked.
Then, every time you click it, the sub menu used will be visible

Comment: Unrelated note: the `!click == true` is  unnecessary since by definition when the else is reached click is false.

Comment: This makes this very far from a MCVE. We cannot perform online debugging with just this code even if we wanted to. "I have already compiled the program and it makes it perfect" ... you are using a debugger, right?